# Ruby on Rails/Rack Builder "Use" Method Wrong Number of Arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, ruby-1.9.3

I am new to Ruby and Rails. I am playing with Rack, trying to get a basic understanding of this peice of the Rails puzzle, following along with Rob Conery in his Tekpub/Rails 3 tutorial vid.

Unfortunately, the version of Rack used in the vid has become long in the tooth, and I think something has changed in between the video release and now (as have some things in Ruby between 1.8.x and 1.9.x). Even more unfortunately, I don't yet know enough about Ruby or Rack to know how to figure out what I need to do differently. The version of Rack used in the video is 1.1. The version on my machine is 1.4.5.

Silly example code:

```
class EnvironmentOutput

  def intialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    out = ""

    unless(@app.nil?)
      response = @app.call(env)[1]
      out+=response
    end

    env.keys.each {|key| out+="<li>#{key}=#{env[key]}"}
    ["200", {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, [out]]
  end

end


class MyApp
  def call(env)
    ["200", {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, ["<h1>Hello There</h1>"]]    
  end
end

# My understanding is that this should work:
use EnvironmentOutput
run MyApp.new
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
```

This is where the first in a series of errors occurs (line 82 in the rack `Builder` class):

```
def use(middleware, *args, &block)
  if @map
    mapping, @map = @map, nil
    @use << proc { |app| generate_map app, mapping }
  end
  # error occurs HERE:
  @use << proc { |app| middleware.new(app, *args, &block) }
end
```

Obviously, I am passing something incorrectly. Sadly, I don't yet know enough to figure out what it is I am doing wrong. I have searched on Google and here on SO, but I suspect I also don't have quite a strong enough grasp on the Ruby/Rails/Rack relationship to know what to ask and get a reasonably helpful result (or, if I AM, then I don't yet recognize it).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

UPDATE: Thanks to the selected answer, I realize it was a typo. Next issue is an array-to-string conversion problem in the same code, but will post as new question.

Comment: Could you show the whole stack trace?

Comment: I though about it, but figured I would wait until asked, as it was large, and somebody might have immediately noticed the problem in my junior-league Ruby code. Which is precisely what happened!  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s just a typo:

```
def intialize(app)
```

should be

```
def initialize(app)
```

(you’ve missed an `i`).

Since you don’t provide an `initialize` method, Ruby tries to use the default, argument-less one, but since Rack passes an argument (the app) you get the `ArgumentError`.

Comment: Well, don't I feel the complete fool! Created a new problem, though. At the line `out+=response` it gives an error "can't convert Array into String." Far as I can tell, the variable out is a string, and the response variable is set to the third element in the array returned by MyApp.call(env). Again, I think I am missing something fundamental. Can post as new question if you think best . . .

Comment: Allow me to say I fell completely retarded, and like I am starting all over a the beginning. Which, I guess, I am in a way. :-)